# Is there a way to get all last record for conditions in array in ActiveRecord Rails in a single query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This what i need. For table `X` there is column `name`.

```
`{:id => 1,:name => a}
 {:id => 2,:name => b}
 {:id => 3,:name => a}
 {:id => 4,:name => b}`
```

The about hash list is table `X` content. Now i want to select last record for name `['a','b']`.

`X.where(:name => ['a','b'])` will give me all records but i want only id => [3,4] (i.e) last record added with name `a` and `b`, and I want to use only a single query.

Comment: I am not sure but can't you try like this `X.where(:name=>['a', 'b']).order('created_at DESC').first`

Comment: Try my answer, it should resolve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this,

```
X.group(:name).having('created_at = MAX(created_at)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for get only id:

```
X.where(name: ['a','b']).group(:name).maximum(:id)
```

Comment: But it is not done at one shot right. For name a it will query the DB and for name b it will query the DB again. what i need is this should be done in single query.